# Auditable actions on database users

Tags: sql, oracle

The query below is meant to retrieve actions by users and pull information from  yesterday. The issue even though the where clause specifies event_timestamp from yesterday it seems to be pulling information from the beginning of the month and secondly I need to pull actions (query executed by the user,how can I achieve this as I tried using sql_text column but it's of a data type clob hence it can not be referenced. see query below:

```
SELECT
    OS_USERNAME,
    DBUSERNAME,
    TERMINAL,
    EVENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ACTION_NAME,
    OBJECT_NAME,
    decode(RETURN_CODE, 0, 'Successful', 'Failed') RETURN_CODE
FROM
    unified_audit_trail
WHERE
    action_name like 'ALTER USER%'
    or action_name like 'CREATE USER%'
    or action_name like 'DROP USER%'
    AND event_timestamp between Trunc(SYSDATE -1) AND Trunc(SYSDATE);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What makes you believe that the data is from the beginning of the month if the `event_teimstamp` is between midnight yesterday and midnight today?  Why can't you reference a `clob` column?  In the initial version of your previous question, you were querying data over a database link which does create some issues for `clob` columns but I have no idea if that's the actual issue.

Comment: What does `perl` have to do with your question? If the answer is "nothing", then why is your question tagged with `perl`? On the other hand, if the question does have something to do with `perl`, then by all means, do share that with us!

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the data being from "before yesterday" is trivial; in my opinion, people who are confused about the order of precedence of logical operators (`or`, `and`, `not`) should not write code, other than in the process of learning - and at the same time that they take a remedial course in logic.

`3 + 2 + 5 = 10`, but `3 + 2 + 5 * 7` is not `10 * 7 = 70`. Look:

```
select 3 + 2 + 5 * 7 as result from dual;

    RESULT
----------
        40        --  the result is not 70!
```

Do you understand why?

What's more, the way to fix this simple arithmetic computation to get the "expected" result of 70 is ***exactly*** the way to fix your `where` clause.

As for your second question - what do you mean by "reference", as in "hence it can not be referenced"? Do you mean you can not `select` it, since it's a `clob`? Why not? I can do that perfectly well on my system; modifying your query just a bit to show that you can select `sql_text` perfectly fine:

```
SELECT
    DBUSERNAME,
    EVENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ACTION_NAME,
    OBJECT_NAME,
    decode(RETURN_CODE, 0, 'Successful', 'Failed') RETURN_CODE,
    SQL_TEXT
FROM
    unified_audit_trail
WHERE
    dbusername != 'SYS' and action_name like 'ALTER USER%' and rownum <= 4;


DBUSERNAME EVENT_TIMESTAMP         ACTION_NAME OBJECT_NAME RETURN_CODE SQL_TEXT                                  
---------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------------------
SYSTEM     2018-04-27 15:41:46.120 ALTER USER  HR          Successful  alter user "HR" identified by * account unlock
ORDS_TEST  2020-03-21 13:41:55.811 ALTER USER  ORDS_TEST   Successful  alter user "ORDS_TEST" grant connect through ORDS_PUBLIC_USER
MATHGUY    2020-11-12 10:05:12.304 ALTER USER  GRAPH       Successful  ALTER USER "GRAPH"                                                              
                                                                       DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"                                                      
                                                                       TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"                                                     
                                                                       ACCOUNT UNLOCK
MATHGUY    2020-11-12 10:05:12.377 ALTER USER  GRAPH       Successful  ALTER USER "GRAPH" QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS
```